# Compilation error in Makefile, includes not showing up

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, g++, compilation

I have a makefile as follows:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)" $(INCLUDES)
ifdef DEBUG
CFLAGS += -g3
endif

INCLUDES = \
-I../config.include \
-I../log.include \
-I../services.include

SRC_DIR = src
BIN_DIR = bin
BINARY  = report

SRCS = $(shell ls $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
OBJS = $(SRCS:%.cpp=%.o)

all: $(OBJS)
    @mkdir -p $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$(BINARY)

clean:
    rm -rf $(BIN_DIR) $(OBJS)
```

However, when I run make, I get the error:

```
g++     -c -o src/report.o src/report.cpp
src/report.cpp:40:20: error: log.h: No such file or directory
src/report.cpp:41:28: error: services.h: No such file or directory
src/report.cpp:41:28: error: config.h: No such file or directory
```

I know for a fact that the header files are there, and that they are included correctly. The paths are also correct. There is something wrong with the makefile, but I cannot figure out what.

Notice that even though I set CC = gcc, the output is always g++. This is not a typo, it is actually the output I am getting - again, not sure why.

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to redefine `CXXFLAGS` and `CXX` and not `CFLAGS` and `CC` for .cpp files.

Check the output of `make -p` and search for `%.o: %.cpp` rule.

Comment: Thank you! I don't have much experience with Makefiles, but that should have been a hint.

Answer (score 0):

You have no target for the individual object files (`$(OBJS)`), so Make searches its list of implicit rules, one of which is to make `.o` files from `.cpp` files using the C++ compiler, which is set by `CXX` (which by default is probably g++).